# How to generate a routing.ts file in a Angular Project

Tags: angular, angular-cli

Is there a command for Angular CLI, wherein I can generate a routing.ts file? So far I have only researched for `ng g m moduleName --routing` which is not I want, because it only created `module-Name-routing.module.ts`. What I want is module-Name.routing.ts. Please help. Thank you

Comment: The CLI generates a routing module for a feature module with the command you mentioned. The naming convention is chosen because routing files are modules, and are linked to their feature modules. Any specific reasoning behind wishing to go against convention?

Comment: I thought there were schematics in angular cli that can generate a routing.ts file. I am currently practicing angular, and I somehow encountered a tutorial with a routing.ts file on it. Thanks for the information.

Comment: No worries. Sounds like the tutorial goes against convention, maybe switch to a different one ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By convention, routing modules end with `module.ts` just like any other modules. Angular will not generate a file ending with `routing.ts`. You would have to manually change the file name, then update the import in `app.module.ts`, but I don't really see the point.

You can follow this tutorial to add a routing module:

https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5

You can specify the name of the routing module during this command

`ng generate module your-name-here --flat --module=app`

If you insist on going against convention, then generate the module as above and change the file name manually. Then go to `app.module.ts` and you will see an import similar to this one:

```js
import { MyRoutingModule } from './my-module-name.module';
```

Correct the import statement and you're good to go

```js
import { MyRoutingModule } from './my-module-name.routing';
```

Comment: Oh I see Thank you. I am currently practicing angular, and I just saw a tutorial in a blog with a routing.ts file. I did not know that it was against the convention. Thanks again